# What is the Groovy API, and what are these classes used for?

Tags: java, api, class, groovy

I'm not asking about the "Groovy JDK API Documentation", which consists of about 100 classes, most of them pre-existing Java classes, and showing the enhancements of them which Groovy provides.

When you download "documentation" from the [Groovy download page](http://groovy-lang.org/download.html) and unpack you find 4 folders under "html". One is called "groovy-jdk" and is the above Groovy JDK API Documentation.

But another is called "gapi" (frames) and another "api" (no frames) and when you click on index.html of either a Javadoc shows hundreds of baffling classes: it starts in the frame version with `classorg.codehaus.groovy.syntax.ASTHelper`, *"A common base class of AST helper methods which can be shared across the classic and new parsers"*, and goes on to (Script) `org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.genMathModification`. Online version (without frames) [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/).

Can anyone explain what these hundreds of classes are, who uses them and under what circumstances? Are they just new classes introduced by Groovy but which don't happen to be enhancements of existing Java classes?

Comment: `AST` stands for `Abstract Syntax Tree`. That `ASTHelper` and many of the other classes seem to be related to compiler side of Groovy, intended for those writing compiler extensions. If you are a user and just write groovy files, you probably don't have to deal with any of it. I expect that anything that doesn't start with `groovy.` in its class name is internal stuff.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, they seem to mix in "internal stuff" with user stuff: Groovy annotations (such as `Slf4j`) are listed there, and also  classes such as `groovy.util.slurpersupport.*` are for use by low-level users such as me (in this case along with `XmlSlurper` - also one of these classes). It'd be nice to know where more details of the "user-facing" classes here can be found.

Comment: Well, Java also mixes general-level things with low-level things (take a look at `LambdaMetafactory`, `CallSite` or `ConstantDesc`, for example).